# Json marshal map of structs results in empty object

Tags: go

I have a simple object defined:

```
type Link struct {
    Href  string `json:"href"`
    Title string `json:"href,omitempty"`
}

type Foo struct {
    Links    map[string]Link     `json:"_links"`
}

foo := new(Foo)
foo.Links = make(map[string]Link, 0)
foo.Links["self"] = Link{Href: "/href"}
```

After marshalling it to JSON, I'd expect:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/href"
        }
    }
}
```

But instead I get:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {}
    }
}
```

Any idea why? Here's a full example:

https://play.golang.org/p/3RA3Mrx3pt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined `json:"href"` twice:

```
type Link struct {
    Href  string `json:"href"`
    Title string `json:"href,omitempty"`
}
```

After changing the second to `json:"title"` it works: https://play.golang.org/p/uEbyqtHYF8.

Comment: Thanks. That's so obvious. How come I didn't see that? Ty :)